# Does knockout re-evaluate inside a virtual element that's been removed

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js

My current template is something like following:

```
<!-- ko 'if': condition -->
    <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
        ...
    </ul>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko ifnot: condition -->
    <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
        ...
    </ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Does it make sense to change it into following

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <!-- ko 'if': $parent.condition -->
        ...
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko ifnot: $parent.condition -->
        ...
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

My actual use case is to have both a list view and a grid view - because their doms are different, I can't just swap some classes on the parent `ul` block.

I wonder which approach is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your original approach is likely preferable, as there will be less overhead with evaluating the `if` and `ifnot` bindings for each item (which includes saving off the child elements as a "template").

Comment: Thx, that's good because the first one is easier to keep track. Just wondering if there is an easy way to see if a binding has fired or not (the debug version of ko?), then we can be sure virtual element remove the second foreach before it fire/update.

Comment: An `if` or `ifnot` will not attempt to bind the children at all, so the inner `foreach` will not have been run or have collected any dependencies.

Comment: An interesting way to test it might be to add `afterRender` parameter to the `foreach` loop, just tested and confirm the removed `foreach` binding does not fire.